# How to remove colored background of minibuffer prompt?

Tags: faces, minibuffer

I modified my `init.el`-file. I added cursor-modifications and [airline-themes](https://github.com/AnthonyDiGirolamo/airline-themes).
When I want to find a file however, this ugly yellow box occurs. I looked around in my init.el, but I did not find anything suspicious.

[image: Yellow box]

Here is my `init.el` with only the important parts:

```
;; cursor color
(setq evil-default-cursor       '("DodgerBlue1" box)

    evil-normal-state-cursor  '("#C3A30E" box)
    evil-emacs-state-cursor   '("yellow" box)
    evil-motion-state-cursor  '("SeaGreen1" box)
    evil-insert-state-cursor  '(box)
    evil-visual-state-cursor  '(box)
    evil-replace-state-cursor '(box))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(airline-cursor-colors nil)
 '(airline-eshell-colors nil)
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(custom-safe-themes
   '("d80952c58cf1b06d936b1392c38230b74ae1a2a6729594770762dc0779ac66b7" default))
 '(menu-bar-mode nil)
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(powerline-evil airline-themes lsp-java undo-tree ivy lsp-pyright company-jedi company use-package el-search treeview gruvbox-theme eglot))
 '(tool-bar-mode nil)
 '(warning-suppress-types '((emacs) (emacs) (emacs) (emacs) (emacs) (emacs) (emacs))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:family "Source Code Pro" :foundry "ADBO" :slant normal :weight normal :height 100 :width normal)))))

;;evil
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil/")
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)


;;emacs theme
(load-theme 'gruvbox-dark-hard t)

;;emacs airline
(require 'airline-themes)
;; (load-theme 'airline-light t)
(load-theme 'airline-base16_gruvbox_dark_hard t)
```

There are other possible costumizations with "M-x customize: airline". But I couldn't find any setting to change that. Thanks for any help in advance.

[image: Airline customization!]

Comment: Did you try bisecting your init.el file? I mean, try removing one piece of configuration at the time and see what happens when you restart Emacs.

Comment: @ManuelUberti Well when I remove any of  the emacs-state... I get an error. But I didn't try the ones where it said nil, because this is pointless anyway..

Comment: What error did you get? You can also try installing airline-themes in `emacs -Q` to avoid clashes with your existing setup, and see if the colour you don't like appear there as well. If it's there, then it's something related to the theme and you may have to look for the right face to change.

Comment: From a cursory look at the source code of the theme, I see it changes `minibuffer-prompt` (https://github.com/AnthonyDiGirolamo/airline-themes/blob/master/airline-themes.el#L485). I think you can just customize that face to remove the background.

Comment: @ManuelUberti That will probably work. How do I edit this though? I will try and figure it out, but a hint would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I think `M-x customize-face RET minibuffer-prompt RET` should get you started.

Comment: For further reference, `C-h r m Face Customization RET` should give you more information about setting faces in Emacs.

Comment: @ManuelUberti Oh nice. I was looking somewhere else.. I just added the picture above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a cursory look at the source code of the theme you are using, I see it changes `minibuffer-prompt` (See: https://github.com/AnthonyDiGirolamo/airline-themes/blob/master/airline-themes.el#L485).

You can move the cursor on the minibuffer prompt and use `M-x describe-face RET` to see the face in use. That's how I discovered `minibuffer-prompt` was involved.

You can then proceed with `M-x customize-face RET minibuffer-prompt RET` and remove the background or tweak it to whatever you prefer. See `C-h r m Face Customization RET` for further details about customizing faces.

Comment: I now have a way to colorize it in a different way. But can I remove it completely? When I uncheck the boxes, they'll be there still after I restart emacs. Probably this face is just required? (and I made sure to save the settings) I should probably try and get the background to match my color scheme. That way, it won't be visible and I got what I wanted.. EDIT: It looks decent enough. Thanks for the help! :)